# Remove Unity Hub logo animation?

Tags: unity3d

Unity Hub (the launcher program to open Unity projects and install editors) introduced a logo splash screen animation in a recent version. (Not to be confused with the splash screen Unity puts into compiled builds, which can be removed in the Player settings.) As I open this program frequently throughout the day, I wanted to get rid of that. Does anyone know how? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/) to get the download link for older Unity Hub.
Lastly, use [Unity Hub release notes](https://unity.com/unity-hub/release-notes) to find out the date of The Unity Hub version you want released.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.